# How to correctly override a class method in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

How to correctly override a class method of this class preview_handler (), whether it is possible to make it in a child class?

```
class WP_some_class {

public function __construct() {
add_action( 'wp', array( $this, 'process' ) );

$this->steps  = (array) apply_filters( 'submit_job_steps', array(
    'submit' => array(
        'name'     => __( 'Submit Details', 'wp-job-manager' ),
        'view'     => array( $this, 'submit' ),
        'handler'  => array( $this, 'submit_handler' ),
        'priority' => 10
        ),
    'preview' => array(
        'name'     => __( 'Preview', 'wp-job-manager' ),
        'view'     => array( $this, 'preview' ),
        'handler'  => array( $this, 'preview_handler' ),
        'priority' => 20
    ),
    'done' => array(
        'name'     => __( 'Done', 'wp-job-manager' ),
        'view'     => array( $this, 'done' ),
        'priority' => 30
    )
) );

public function preview_handler() {
    // .. some code
}

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can simply extend the class.

```
class Extending_class extends WP_some_class
{
    public function preview_handler()
    {
        // Your code
    }
}
```

Beware that you have to mantain the same method parameters (no one, in this case) as the original class.

From the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php):

> [...] when you extend a class, the subclass inherits all of the public and protected methods from the parent class. Unless a class overrides those methods, they will retain their original functionality.